# How to connect android emulator to api service

Tags: php, api, cordova, android-emulator

I have problem connect android emulator to `api service` with `php`.
my app build with `cordova` but can't connect because android emulator
not same subnet address localhost or `127.0.0.1` or `::1`. how to solved my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead for default AVD and 10.0.3.2 for genymotion.